# Swapped surname and given name in both passport and US multiple-entry visa

Tags: visas, usa

My wife's passport and US visa have her given name and surname swapped. Since it matches in both we have been travelling without hassles for years on visitor's multiple-entry 10-year visas, valid until 2029.

Now I would like to have it rectified. Should I first get a new passport and then apply for a fresh visa, or is there a different form for correction?

Comment: What is her nationality and if she lives in a different country, which one?